# What does the suffix -ida mean?

Tags: definiciones

what does the suffix "-ida" mean?

Academia real gives this definition

1. suf. Forma sustantivos derivados de verbos de la segunda y tercera conjugación, que generalmente significan 'acción y efecto'.

What would `subida` mean? From `Subir`

Comment: Hi June, welcome to Spanish.SE! Your question is a bit unclear. Well either that, or you pretty much answered yourself. I'd suggest you rewrite it so that we can better know what to answer.

Answer (score 2):

What the *Academia Real* says by

> Forma sustantivos derivados de verbos de la segunda y tercera conjugación, que generalmente significan 'acción y efecto'.

is that you would use this suffix with verbs ending in -er and -ir (segunda y tercera conjugación) like "com**er**" and "sub**ir**" (but not "and**ar**").

The meaning of the suffix conveys "this is a result or action of doing verb XXX", but this implication can go beyond "cause and effect".

- Subir --> Subida (among other meanings "ascensión, lugar donde comienza una ascensión...")
- Salir --> Salida (Among other meanings, "lugar por donde se sale")
- Beber --> bebida ("algo que se puede beber")
- Comer --> Comida ("algo que se puede comer")
- Herir (hacer daño) --> Herida (Daño recibido)

Answer (score 1):

*Subida* means "ascent"; loosely explained, given that *subir* means "to go up", *subida* would mean "what you do when yo go up" (*acción*) or "the result of you going up" (*efecto*).

Comment: "Subida" as "the result of you going up" sounds a bit weird. I would translate "subida" as a noun as the surface consisting in some change of level. "La subida del Tourmalet tiene 5 km"

Comment: Maybe it's not explained in proper linguistic terms, but that's actually what it is: _Hice la subida a la colina_ = "I made the ascent to the hill", the _subida_ (ascent) being what you completed upon _subir_ (go up) the hill. What you wrote would be a synonim for "slope" or "height".

Comment: There was a mistake in my previous sentence, I meant "la subida *al* Tourmalet". But it is still a valid sentence (seen [everywhere](http://www.elmundo.es/elmundodeporte/especiales/ciclismo/tour/2010/la-subida-al-tourmalet.html)!) I don't know if you mean it is incorrect. *Hice la subida a la colina* sounds a bit weird to me, honestly, we would directly say *Subí la colina*.

Comment: Yes, of course your sentence is right, but _subida_ is used there as meaning "height". Regarding _Hice la subida a la colina_, yes, you would rarely use that form, but it' not wrong; I used it just to give an example of _subida_ meaning "effect of _subir_".

Comment: Mmmm yes, I would say it is the "6. f. Lugar por donde se sube." in http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=subida

Answer (score 1):

The DRAE has an entry for [subida](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=IT55ZYqI0DXX26f5ZZBm%7Cigzqj987fDXX2nlD93H1). It is basically

> Acción y efecto de subir

but can also mean other things, like the place where you start an ascension

> Este es el camino de subida a la montaña.

For a color or smell, means to be *very intense*

> Se enfadó tanto que se puso de un rojo subido.

It works as an intensifier with other adjetives:

> Ese chico tiene el guapo muy subido  <sub>(That guy has heard that he is handsome so many times that he is starting to act annoyingly)</sub>
>
> Ese es un chiste subido de tono  <sub>(That joke is not appropriate for some audiences)</sub>

Comment: I think what is being asked is not actually the meaning of _subida_ but how nouns are derived from actions or effects, using _subida_ as an example.

Comment: I think there are kind of two questions in the post. I don't know if the OP is asking specifically about "subida" or if he or she provided that just as an example and misled a little bit the answers. I just posted a different answer to address the first part of the question, abut the suffixes, that I understood the OP answered him or herself by quoting the RAE. Maybe the OP didn't understand the RAE's explanation and is looking for clarification on that.